# A single equation that encapsulates all the axioms of an algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group can be seen as the minimum requirements needed to solve for $x$ in $ax=b$, as in first you need inverses to get
$$a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}b$$
and then need associativity to get
$$(aa^{-1})x=a^{-1}b$$
and finally an identity to get
$$ex=x=a^{-1}b$$
hence solving for $x$. Are there synonymous 'minimal equations' that characterize all the axioms of, say, a ring or a field?

Comment: I don't believe that a group cannot be seen that way. Loops appear to satisfy your axiom. And you know that $ax=x$ has a solution $a=e$. But why should the same $e$ work for different $x$.

Comment: While in any group the equation $ax=b$ is always solvable, there are structures in which the equation $ax=b$ always has a solution (in fact, always has a *unique* solution) but are not groups; for one thing, they need not be associative. But even if you throw in associativity: for example, take any set $S$ with at least two elements and define the multiplication by $ab=b$ for all $a,b\in S$. Then $ax=b$ always has the unique solution $b$. However, this is not a group. So you are incorrect that this equation "characterizes groups".

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean.  As pointed out in the other comments, $\forall a, b\exists_1 x(ax = b)$ holds in structures other than groups. If you mean that the solution to $ax = b$ can be expressed in terms of $a$ and $b$ using the group operations, then you don't need $e$ to **express** the solution as $a^{-1}b$.

Comment: Just as a facetious comment: there are 7,580,721,483,160,132,811,489,280 non-isomorphic structures satisfying your axiom (multiplication is a bijection) of size $10$. There are two groups of size $10$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: fascinating observation. How did you get the first number?

Comment: @RobArthan All the author is defining is a Latin square, since they only need that multiplication on one side is a bijection. That is the number of Latin squares up to reordering. Now I think of it, perhaps it's even weaker than Latin square.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: I see. I think it is weaker than the Latin square property: e.g., see Arturo's comment.

Comment: @RobArthan Indeed. So the number is much, much higher!